# If am entering some values in text box it should be simultaneously displayed in the other text box using html and js

Tags: javascript, html

If am entering some values in text box it should be simultaneously displayed in other text box using html and js in the same page.

That is if i enter **test** in text box then the other text box should contain the alphabet **test** immediately.

Is that possible. If yes how?

kindly clarify.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `onkeydown` event, combined with a timer that will execute immediately afterwards:

```
textbox1.onkeydown = function () { 
    window.setTimeout(function () { textbox2.value = textbox1.value; }, 0);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rA9W7/)

For Opera, you will need to use `onkeypress` to capture repeated input (holding the key down).

Comment: Do you need the `setTimeout` there? (I’m sure you do, I just can’t see why off the top of my head.)

Comment: @Paul: events that can be cancelled fire *before* their action, so not using the timer would result in the previous value being copied to the other text box.